# Connect macbook to my LAN through a VPN - best solution?

Tags: macos, vpn, lan, freenas

So I have a LAN connected via a ADSL/PPPoA, this is using a bog-standard DLink router supplied by my ISP (talktalk UK).

I have a NAS within the LAN that is running FreeNAS and I want to be able to connect to it when I'm out and about. It's running an atom so it's quite low on juice consumption but I don't want to have it on all day and night so I've been waking it via a magic packet and booting it down from the web admin when I need it.

So I want to connect to the LAN, I presume via a VPN, to be able to send a magic packet. But what is the best method to accomplish this, or is there an easier way?

I've been looking at the cisco 857 integrated router and the Netgear prosafe 318(behind modem) but not sure If I'm on the right track with what I want to achieve as I've not much experience or knowledge with VPN's or networking (software engineering student).

I have tried port forwarding but to no avail, either with magic packets or even connecting outside the LAN via DYNDNS.

Thanks,